# workless is not working (it is not starting a Heroku worker dyno)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I have the following in the `Gemfile` of a `Rails` project, yet `workless` (https://github.com/lostboy/workless) is not working (it is not starting a Heroku worker dyno when a job is added to the `Delayed::Job` queue).

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'workless'
gem 'daemons'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a silent error, so I just ended up figuring it out after quite some time.

[As per the gem's instructions](https://github.com/lostboy/workless): *Add your Heroku app name / API key as config vars to your Heroku instance.*

```
heroku config:add HEROKU_API_KEY=yourapikey APP_NAME=yourherokuappname
```

Get `yourapikey` from https://dashboard.heroku.com/account and `yourherokuappname` from https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps

Also, if you are using a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to declare *what commands are run by your application's dynos on the Heroku platform*, there is **NO** need for a `worker` line (`worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work`) in `Procfile` -- that would only be need if you were *not* using `workless`.

Answer (score 2):

So this is something I ran into setting up a new Heroku account for a friend. No credit card on file. Although their is free time on the account, the account will be blocked from doing the sort of things that might incur charges without credit information on file.

Just FYI for anyone that runs into this and has everything set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For people who will have similar problems, if you have some worker which you need to run all the time (not delayed job e.g) and you have some other which you would like to run with workless.

Define the independent worker as a separate process in the Procfile and don't use the word 'worker' in it's name, because of https://github.com/lostboy/workless/blob/master/lib/workless/scalers/heroku_cedar.rb#L18